# How to control the cursor during slide show?

Tags: user-interface

I often use Mathematica slide presentations in class.  I would like to keep the standard arrow cursor (or one of my own choosing) during slide presentations. The default behavior over text cells is a vertical bar (which is almost invisible). Is there a configuration setting or a programmatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a function `MouseApparance` and you could try to use with created cells if you don't need to edit them but for general case I think the answer is no. This is one question hanging around for quite some time: [How to change Mathematica cursor globally?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21634/5478)

Comment: You can create your own mouse pointer scheme and switch to it for presentations using the settings in your operating system.